# How to block crawling and indexing of URLs generated by APIs?

Tags: html, bots, web-crawler

We have used APIs of financial data to generate stock market updates. The API widget has a dropdown section to scroll through different options to know a list of stocks from different metrics, for example Top Losers, Top Gainers etc, are some of the options in the dropdown.

However, for each of these sections, a new URL is created (for example [www.abc.com?mm-opions=52-week,www.abc.com?mm-opions=top-gainers](http://www.abc.com?mm-opions=52-week,www.abc.com?mm-opions=top-gainers) etc.) and the new URL gets indexed in Google SERPs. This causes duplicate content issues as 4-5 versions of the same URL are indexed. Can anybody suggest a solution on how I can block the extra URLs from getting crawled and indexed?